# main.cpp(12): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'vec1'

Tags: c++

I dont know what is wrong with my code, but it gives this error.

> main.cpp(12): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'vec1'.

There was no problem declaring a vector of vector like this in the constructor, but I can't seem to do it as a class member.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class vecList
{
private:
    int row, column, vec1, vec2, part;
    vector< vector <int> > vEC(vec1,vector<int>(vec2));

public:
    vecList(int vRow, int vColumn, int vPart)
    {
        cin >> vRow;
        cin >> vColumn;
        row = vRow;
        column = vColumn;
        vector< vector <int> > vEC(vColumn, vector<int>(vRow));
        for(int i = 0; i < vColumn; i++)
        {
            cout << endl  << "|";
            for(int j = 0; j < vRow; j++)
            {
                vEC[i][j] = 14;
                cout << vEC[i][j] << "|";
            }
        }    
    }

    void getValue()
    {
        int a, b;
        a = column;
        b = row;
        cout << a << b;
    }
};
int main()
{
vecList a(2,4,6);
a.getValue();
a.getVect();
}
```

Comment: @RemyLebeau No, the error says it's in main *.cpp* not the main function. And it's right there too, `vector< vector <int> > vEC(vec1,vector<int>(vec2));` is not a valid thing to do.

Comment: `vEC(vec1,vector<int>(vec2));` needs to go to the constructor initializer list.

Comment: @Borgleader oh why? can you explain a little more on details?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your class declaration:

```
vector< vector <int> > vEC(vec1,vector<int>(vec2));
```

Is not a valid declaration of a data member.  One, because it is invalid syntax, and two, because the values of `vec1` and `vec2` are unknown when the member is constructed.

Try something more like this instead:

```
class vecList
{
private:
    int row, column, part;
    vector< vector<int> > vEC;

public:
    vecList(int vRow, int vColumn, int vPart)
    {
        /* these values are provided by the caller, so you shouldn't
        be reading them from std::cin here.  That is the caller's
        responsibility to do instead...
        cin >> vRow;
        cin >> vColumn;
        */

        row = vRow;
        column = vColumn;
        part = vPart;

        vEC.resize(vColumn);
        for(int i = 0; i < vColumn; i++)
        {
            vEC[i] = vector<int>(vRow);
            cout << endl  << "|";
            for(int j = 0; j < vRow; j++)
            {
                vEC[i][j] = 14;
                cout << vEC[i][j] << "|";
            }
        }    
    }

    ...
};
```

Which can be simplified to this:

```
class vecList
{
private:
    int row, column, part;
    vector< vector <int> > vEC;

public:
    vecList(int vRow, int vColumn, int vPart)
        : row(vRow), column(vColumn), part(vPart), vEC(vColumn, vector<int>(vRow, 14))
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < vColumn; i++)
        {
            cout << endl  << "|";
            for(int j = 0; j < vRow; j++)
            {
                cout << vEC[i][j] << "|";
            }
        }    
    }

    ...
};
```

Comment: why is it wrong syntax? Same syntax was used in the constructor.

Comment: @NONONONONO: `vector< vector <int> > vEC(vec1,vector<int>(vec2));` is declaring a local variable named `vEC` *AND* initializing it by passing values to its constructor at the same time. You can't do that in a class member declaration (well, in C++11 you can, but the syntax is different). You have to either 1) let the member be default-constructed and then manipulate it afterwards, as shown in my 1st example, or 2) use the parent class's constructor initialization list to pass values to a member's constructor, as shown in my 2nd example.

Answer (score 0):

Well first, you dont have a main - therefore, your program cannot run.
Second of all, you need to define the type of the variable of vec1 in your decliration of vEC.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class vecList

{
private:
    int row, column, vec2, part;
    vector< vector <int> > vEC(int(vec1), vector<int>(vec2));

public:
    vecList(int vRow, int vColumn, int vPart)
    {
        cin >> vRow;
        cin >> vColumn;
        row = vRow;
        column = vColumn;
        vector< vector <int> > vEC(vColumn, vector<int>(vRow));
        for (int i = 0; i<vColumn; i++)
        {
            cout << endl << "|";
            for (int j = 0; j<vRow; j++)
            {
                vEC[i][j] = 14;
                cout << vEC[i][j] << "|";
            }
        }
    }
    void getValue()    {
        int a, b;
        a = column;
        b = row;
        cout << a << b;
    }
};

int main()
{
/*...Your code here...*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best idea would be to let the constructor initialize the vector.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class vecList
{
    public:
        vecList(int vRow, int vColumn, int vPart)
            :
            vec1(vColumn),
            vec2(vRow),
            part(vPart),
            vEC(vec1, vector<int>(vec2))
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < vColumn; i++)
            {
                cout << endl << "|";

                for(int j = 0; j < vRow; j++)
                {
                    vEC[i][j] = 14;
                    cout << vEC[i][j] << "|";
                }

                cout << endl;
            }
        }

        void getValue()
        {
            int a, b;
            a = column;
            b = row;
            cout << a << b;
        }

    private:
        int row, column, vec1, vec2, part;
        vector< vector <int> > vEC;

};

int main()
{
    vecList veclist(3, 4, 2);
    veclist.getValue();
    return 0;
}
```